# Dynamic routes in express based on external api data

Tags: api, express, routes, vimeo

I need to automatically generate the routes on an expressjs app, based on the vimeo api

I thought that I need to loop through the api data, save the data in the db and then retrieve that data in a middleware. For example:

Api request:

```js
    const Vimeo = require("vimeo").Vimeo;
    let client = new Vimeo("CLIENT_ID", "CLIENT_SECRET", "TOKEN");

    client.request(
     {
       method: "GET",
       path: "/my/path/videos"
     },
      function(error, body, status_code, headers) {
       if (error) {
        console.log(error);
       }
       let data = body.data;

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // save data in the db
      }          
   });
```

Middleware:

```js
app.use('/videos/:name', (req, res, next) {
    if (req.params.name === myDBdata) {
        console.log('It works!');
        next();
    } else {
      // error code
    }
});
```

Is this a good way to proceed? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make a function which takes two paremter like:

```
function makeRoute(path, handler) {
      return app.use(path, handler)
}
```

And then call this for every data

```
makeRoute('test', (req, res) => { })
```